# how to view pdf based on user's upload using html in blazor wasm

Tags: html, blazor, webassembly, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

i want to view my pdf based on user's upload in blazor wasm, i dont know how to use pdf.js

i try this code but i still cant to view my pdf, i get an error like 500

```
    GET https://localhost:44392/api/DocumentImages/GetPDFview?&division=4&department=15&verifyCode=20230614042833945 500
```

@code {

```
#nullable disable
[Parameter]
public int? id { get; set; }
private string PDFData;

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{   
    await PDFImage(employee.Verify_Id, employee.DivisionId, employee.DepartmentId);
}

private async Task PDFImage(string verifyCode, int division, int department)
{
    try
    {
        var Pdfmodel = await _imageService.GetPDFData(verifyCode, division, department);
        if (Pdfmodel != null)
        {
            var base642 = Convert.ToBase64String(Pdfmodel);
            PDFData = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", base642);
            Console.WriteLine($"2nd Test: {verifyCode}");
        }
     
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return;
    }

}
```

}

service:
public async Task<byte[]> GetPDFData(string verifyCode, int division, int department)
{
var _pdf = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<byte[]>($"api/DocumentImages/GetPDFview?&division={division}&department={department}&verifyCode={verifyCode}");
if (_pdf != null)
return _pdf;
throw new Exception("No PDF Found");
}

controller/api:
[HttpGet("GetPDFview")]
public async Task<ActionResult<byte[]>> Getattachmentview([FromQuery] string verifyCode, [FromQuery] int division, [FromQuery] int department)
{
{
var _PDFlist = await _context.DocumentImages.ToListAsync();
var divisionList = _PDFlist.Where(a => a.DivisionId == division).ToList();
var deptList = divisionList.Where(a => a.DepartmentId == department).ToList();
var model = deptList.Where(a => a.Verify_Id == verifyCode).FirstOrDefault();

```
            if (model == null)
            {
                return NotFound("No pdf available");
            }

            var _path = Path.Combine(_evs.ContentRootPath, model.Img_URL, model.Img_Filename);

            var _memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var _stream = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await _stream.CopyToAsync(_memory);
            }
            _memory.Position = 0;
            return _memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
```